# What is Nilkanth Varni holding in his hand?

Tags: meditation, sadhana, swaminarayan

what is the U-shaped thing in Swaminarayan's lefthand in [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Nilkanth_Varni.JPG)? What purpose does it serve?